# Show DataGrid.SelectedItems in a new Window in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an application in C# WPF and it has a DataGrid that takes the values from a SQL DataBase. I want to cheate a MouseDobleClick event that will open a new window with the data what I have selected on my DataGrid. Imagine that my dataGrid is populated with 100 values from my DB. When I double click one of the values (that bassicaly contains personal data) it will open a new window where I can arrange the data to be more readable(also I will show a picture, etc..).
It is possible? I was thinking of creating a report, but I don´t think it will be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is alot of ways to do this .. i am a noob so this one is not the best but it will work with most of the data type

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // a field and property to hold your cell value
   public static string valueofcell;
    public string VALUEOFCELL
    {
        get { return valueofcell; }
        set { valueofcell = value; }
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the cell value and save it to the field we have created
         valueofcell= Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);
        //the show method will make the from appear right after the double click
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.Show();

    }
```

and in ther other form you can use the form load method to show your data in any control you want ..let's say a label

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string x = form1.VALUEOFCELL; ;
        label1.Text = x;
    }
```